# How to run a generic method on a core data entity on Swift, the smarter way

Tags: swift, core-data, swift5

I have a lot of core data entities, they all have this method:

```
class func count(_ context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Int
```

Suppose the entities are called: Car, Bus, Plane, etc.

What I would like to do is this, as I would normally.

```
let carCount = Car.count(coreDataContext)
```

of

```
 let busCount = Bus.count(coreDataContext)
```

but, all I have is the entity name, as described previously

How do I run that method from an entity just by the name of that entity?

Comment: If all you want to do is to count the number of objects then use [count(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count)

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your implementation, but if the code is basically the same you could just extend `NSManagedObject` with that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a protocol with associated type

```
protocol Fetchable
{
    associatedtype FetchableType: NSManagedObject = Self
    static var entityName : String { get }
    static func count(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Int
}
```

and a protocol extension

```
extension Fetchable where Self : NSManagedObject
{
    
    static var entityName : String { return String(describing:self) }

    static func count(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Int
    {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<FetchableType>(entityName: entityName)        
        return try context.count(for: request)
    }
}
```

Adopt `Fetchable` in the `NSManagedObject` subclasses